# Que veut dire "x fois trop" ?

Tags: sens, expressions, expressions-idiomatiques, locutions, mathématiques

Est-ce que *"x fois trop"* signifie la même chose que *"x fois plus"* ? Sinon que veut-il dire *"x fois trop"* ?

Par exemple, s'il faut dépenser 5 euros et qu'on en a dépensé 15, est-ce qu'on peut dire qu'on a dépensé (15÷5) 3 fois trop ? Est-ce pareil de dire qu'on a dépensé 3 fois plus que ce qu'on avait le droit de dépenser ?

Et si on a un fil de 6 m et qu'on a besoin de 42 m, est-ce qu'on peut dire qu'on a un fil qui est (42÷6) 7 fois trop court ?

Et à l'inverse, si on a un fil de 42 m et qu'on n'a besoin que de 6 m, est-ce qu'on peut dire qu'on a un fil qui est (42÷6) 7 fois trop long ?

Comment: réponse courte : oui, oui et oui  ;)

Comment: @XouDo Il y a six questions, donc : non, autre chose, oui, oui, oui et oui !

Answer (score 5):

*Fois **plus*** et *fois **moins*** ne portent pas de jugement de valeur sur la longueur. Il s'agit juste d'une constatation neutre comparant deux mesures.

*Fois **trop*** indique que la taille ne convient pas, que la taille attendue était X fois **plus** petite ou X fois **plus** grande.

Answer (score 0):

Tu peux par exemple utiliser "x fois trop" ironiquement pour désigner quelque chose qui t'a été donné en trop grande quantité.
Si on te sert beaucoup plus de nourriture que ta faim tu peux donc dire qu'il y en a 3, 10, ou 30 fois trop (le chiffre est arbitraire mais témoigne de la proportion).